# ElasticSearch: how to read output of _node/hot_threads

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data node in ElasticSearch that is running high on CPU (99%) and searches are slow. Using `top` reveals it's elasticsearch's process that is using all of the CPU.

I ran the `_nodes/hot_threads` API in that node and I got this output, but I don't know how to interpret it. Could somebody explain?

```
::: {warm-xxx}{XXXXXXX}{YYYYYYYY}{10.10.10.10}{10.10.10.10:9300}{aws_availability_zone=us-west-2b, data_type=warm, ml.machine_memory=64388997120, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.enabled=true}
   Hot threads at 2019-12-30T23:22:24.304Z, interval=500ms, busiestThreads=3, ignoreIdleThreads=true:

   44.0% (220.2ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[warm-xxx][management][T#1]'
     3/10 snapshots sharing following 57 elements
       org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine.segmentsStats(Engine.java:831)
       org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.segmentStats(IndexShard.java:1051)
       org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.stats.CommonStats.<init>(CommonStats.java:213)
       org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.indexShardStats(IndicesService.java:403)
       org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.statsByShard(IndicesService.java:357)
       org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.stats(IndicesService.java:348)
...

   42.7% (213.4ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[warm-xxx][search][T#2]'                                                                                             
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 21 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:263)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:214)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:39)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:670)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:471)
...
   41.8% (208.9ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[warm-xxx][search][T#7]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 21 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:263)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:214)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:39)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:670)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:471)
```

I'm running ElasticSearch 6.8

Comment: Can you add more info: 1. is it happening only on a single node of a cluster or all? 2. Can you take the 3-4 snapshot of 1-sec interval and post it. 3. check and provide the o/p https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html .. there could be multiple caused of hot threads and we need to have more information to debug it efficiently

Comment: We found the issue a moment ago, using `_cat/tasks` we noticed there were searches running for over 6 hours (they had timeout out on our application side a long time ago). So we restarted the ES coordinator node that received those queries and the CPU usage of the nodes went to normal values (~40%).

Comment: I'll still provide the information you requested as soon as this issue happens again. Is there any documentation about how to interpret the hot_threads output? (also, what do you mean by "o/p"?)

Comment: cool, glad you were able to troubleshoot this particular instance, please provide all the information next time and o/p is the shortcut for output :-)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch documentation still doesn't explain the output of this API.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html

But Opensearch explains it a bit more you can check from the following link:
https://opensearch.org/docs/2.6/api-reference/nodes-apis/nodes-hot-threads/

Note: both articles are not good enough to understand what is happening :)

Answer (score -1):

Now it's been more time since I added comment and as there is no answer and detailed document, I am planning to write one which I will share once completed.

But as of now, in short, Elasticsearch uses various threadpools for various operations(search, index, management, analyze etc), you can find all the threadpools and its configuration ie number of threads and queue size on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) official doc.

Now if you closely follow the output of API, it will tell the node name, threadpool name(management and search in your case) and thread number like (T#1, t#7) and what exactly that thread is doing and how much time its taking, so that you can get some idea what are the hot spots in your cluster.

This particular search is very costly as shown in your example

```
41.8% (208.9ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[warm-xxx][search][T#7]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 21 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:263)
       org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:214)
       org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:39)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:670)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:471)
```

So you need to figure out in your application how you are using this search       `org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)` and try to improve it.